# Any attempt to BLE pair using the Windows DeviceEnumeration sample fails

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

When using the Microsoft code sample "DeviceEnumeration" every attempt to pair to a Bluetooth Low Energy device fails. TheDeviceInformationPairing.CanPair = true `and DeviceInformationPairing.ProtectionLevel = none`. The code in question is in the file Scenario8_PairDevice.cs in the PairButton_Click method. The iMac I am trying to pair to displays a pairing dialog the Windows displays a Pair Device dialog with the same pin. I have also tried pairing to an iPhone, iPad, and an stereo receiver with the same results.

Comment: Try to pair after connect: https://github.com/btframework/GattAuth

Comment: Try with a device that is not an Apple device, the one OEM that cannot seem to want to agree with any protocol that the rest of the world has published and implemented international standards.

Comment: It seems like the GattAuth code is more of a commercial advertisement for btlframework library. I am trying to understand what sample code from Microsoft does not seem to work.